# send array from php to android

Tags: java, android, json

Hi i have a DirectoryIterator that is used to store the filepath to all the files in a certain directory in the server .

The php code follows:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
 new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path),
 RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($iterator as $fileObject) {
  $files[] = $fileObject;
}
```

I know that to print the array i would have to use print(json_encode($files[])

But how to decode it on the android side

Comment: `echo json_encde($array);`

Comment: Decoding a json string sent to an android device is a Java issue/question not a php one as your php is fine your question isn't php related.  Re-tagging accordingly

Comment: Yes.. sorry .. what bothers me is that i need to decode it on the android side

Comment: I have Tried JSONOBject . but the array i am sending is a unidimensional array and i haven't found anything on the internet that  transformes a JSON object into a datatype array

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to decode this file. You will be response from server in a JSON or XML format. and parse the json from server response. it will get datatype like string or int.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that .. will it return an array of strings ?

Comment: welcome you use array of string from server then it will be solve your problem.